# Open DOC, DOCX, PPT, PDF inside flutter app

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

How do i open DOC, DOCX, PPT, PDF inside my flutter app. I dont want to open from outside(oter apps). I want to preview the files if possible as a child in my widgets.
I tried the following packages:

flutter_filereader: rejected by playstore(Uses Tencent X5)
PDFTron: Very huge, some PPT file open blank, opens in a separate screen not inside widgets.

Comment: did you try embedding google viewer inside the webview ?

Answer (score 3):

use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to open web url in WebView widget. as

```
var yourLink = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';

WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$yourLink',
);
```

if your file is from local replace yourLink with localPath.

Comment: this method is nice. Could do for this moment am trying to figure out a way. Currently i have my user download the document so as next time can view without internet.

Comment: It's not loading file from local path

Comment: this solution is not for loading the file from local/phone storage. try something else @joshua

Comment: I tried lot no plugin found for to open docx file